# Iam trying to run this code in sql . but gives me a missing keyword error

Tags: sql

```
SELECT order_id,   ordered_quantity,  product_description , standard_price FROM m_product 
JOIN m_order_line 
WHERE product_description = 'End Table' OR product_description = 'Coffee Table' OR product_description   = 'Dining Table'
ORDER BY product_description;
```

Comment: The keyword error comes in line 3 when the (where) statment starts

Comment: `FROM` table1 `JOIN` table2 `ON` join-conditions `WHERE` ...

Comment: i didnt get what you said . sorry iam new to coding

Comment: You do not have a complete `join` condition. Which columns are you joining the tables on? The database doesn't know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define that join perform on which common column
Using **ON** and give  **Alies** to your table

**Alies :- m1 ane m2**
Use Alies as :- **m1.yourcolumn** or **m2.yourcolumn**

```
SELECT 
        order_id,
        ordered_quantity,
        product_description,
        standard_price 
    FROM m_product as m1
    JOIN m_order_line as m2 on m1.columnname = m2.columnname
    WHERE product_description = 'End Table' OR product_description = 'Coffee Table' OR product_description   = 'Dining Table'
    ORDER BY product_description;
```